# Facebook like count with jQuery

Tags: jquery, json, facebook, facebook-graph-api, each

I'm having a little problem: I'm trying to write a jQuery function that loops over all divs which have a specific class and populates them with Facebook's Like count (the required URL is in the `rel` attribute). The problem is that it only takes effect on the last item for some reason.

HTML:

```
<div class="facebook_likes" rel="http://www.somesite.com/"></div>
<div class="facebook_likes" rel="http://www.somesite2.com/"></div>
<div class="facebook_likes" rel="http://www.somesite3.com/"></div>
```

JS:

```
function getLikes() {
    jQuery('.facebook_likes').each(function(){
    currentdiv = jQuery(this);
        url = currentdiv.attr('rel');
    jQuery.getJSON('http://graph.facebook.com/'+url,function(data) {
       currentdiv.text((data.shares || 0)+' Likes');
    });
})

}
```

Thanks!

PS: I'm calling the function on document ready. Fiddle at:
http://jsfiddle.net/Mjzpm/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is very simple.

```
function getLikes() {
    jQuery('.facebook_likes').each(function(){
        var currentdiv = jQuery(this);
        var url = currentdiv.attr('rel');
        jQuery.getJSON('http://graph.facebook.com/'+url,function(data) {
           currentdiv.text((data.shares || 0)+' Likes');
        });
    })
}
```

You need to initialize currentDiv and url on every loop through. By the time the first getJSON completes, the currentDiv/url are now equal to the last value that those two variables were set to.

Comment: thank you! I knew it had to be something simple.. lack of coffee strikes again

Comment: you're welcome! totally understand, easy mistake to make. Please upvote and accept when possible.

Answer (score 0):

At first you have to create a username of your page(see under your page name @username. Just click it...)

Then goto https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/ and get an access token key

Then script something like that

```
function facebookLikesCount(access_token)
{
var url = "https://graph.facebook.com/voucherin.ukbd?fields=likes&access_token="+access_token+"";

$.getJSON(url,function(json){
alert(json.likes);
});
}

facebookLikesCount('your accesstoken');
```